# Convert timestring into date - Python

Tags: python

If I have the following timestring:

```
20150505
```

How would I convert this into the date `May 5, 2015` in Python? So far I've tried:

```
from datetime import datetime
sd = datetime.strptime('20150504', '%Y%M%d')
```

But this outputs:

```
2015-01-04 00:05:00
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The capital `M` denotes minute not month. Use the lowercase `m` and then call the `strftime` method to refactor the format:

```
>>> datetime.strptime('20150504', '%Y%m%d').strftime('%b %d, %Y')
'May 04, 2015'
```

You can remove the zero padding from the month by using the `-d` directive in place of `d`:

> `%-d` Day of the month as a decimal number. **(Platform specific)**

For longer month names, you can use the directive `%B` in place of `%b` to get the full month name.

---

Reference:

http://strftime.org/

Comment: I would suggested amending the anwser, to remove the leading zero from date, as per OP's example format.

Comment: @Marcin That directive is not guaranteed to work on all platforms

Comment: OP does not specify its platorm, python version, or anything. So its difficult to comment on that. But it is still worth to be aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

If you know it's a date and not a datetime, or you don't know the format. You can use dateutil.

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
print(parse('20150504'))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the anwser, wihout leading zero for day, as OP's example:

```
print(sd.strftime('%b %-d, %Y'))
# Jan 4, 2015 # note your sd parsing is wrong. Thus Jan
```

Comment: Not quite. Try that and see what it gives

Comment: @MosesKoledoye I concentraed of formating part, not parsing. So you can join my anwser to yours, to remove 0 from day.